# Java webapp responding the source code of my login page

Tags: java, json, spring, web-services

I have a java web application which publish a service that returns an object in JSON format, and I have another java web app just to consume that service through a JSONP call and show the response. In my local machine it's working fine, but now that I want to test it in a web environment (Layershift in my case), I can't get the JSON object. I don't see any errors on Chrome developer tools, but when I look into the Response tab (in Network option) I see the source code of the login page of my application. Let me show you the my code

Controller with the service:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
@RequestMapping(value="/myservice/get/{somevar}")
public MappingJacksonValue getMyObject (@RequestParam String callback, @PathVariable String somevar, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    //some logic
    MappingJacksonValue value = new MappingJacksonValue(obj);
    value.setJsonpFunction(callback);
    return value;
}
```

}

javascript code for call the service:

```
$.fn.callWithJsonP = function(somevar) {
var url = "/myservice/get/" + somevar + "?callback=myCallback";
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    if (data.value.status == "OK") {
        //shows the data contained
    }
});
}
```

Apache configuration (added to avoid CORS error), present in both applications

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header always unset X-Frame-Options
```

This is working perfectly on muy local machine (except for the Apache, I don't use it locally), but as I said, on a web environment I receive the source code of my login page. In the Headers tab I can see the headers added in Apache, and the status code of the response is OK, any clues about what's goin on?

Kind regards

**UPDATE**
I've removed the Apache web server, and even tested the web service with Postman (meaning, no second application), and still the same result. I've tried changing @RestController for @Controller and returning an instance of MyObject (instead of MappingJacksonValue), with no results, please help me

Comment: If you are seeing the login page seems like the problem is related to Spring security.

Comment: Try this annotation `@CrossOrigin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am probably way off here, but is it possible that you have a servlet filter or other part of your web app config that is routing your get request to your login page before your REST framework is able to map it to your endpoint?  I use Jersey for this usually, so I am unfamiliar with Spring's RestController, but I assume it is doing similar thing - routes URLs that match to the java code.  If you are seeing login page in response it sounds like something is interfering and trying to force user to login before Spring directs to your endpoint method.

Comment: Hi @JimWeaver, nice suggestion, I have a security control but shouldn't catch the requests I'm sending, but I will check it and let you know, regards

Comment: Thank you @JimWeaver, finally it's working, it was a servlet filter failing (I had a couple of errors: folder doesn't exist on web environment, properties file not being loaded, JCE libraries, etc) and somehow redirecting me to the login page, it was not the security configuration, but the servlet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a fallback set in your server, maybe configured for a single page application. This is normally used for routing with HTML5 mode using routers like angular's.

Comment: It's something like this: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

Comment: Hi @DavidMantilla, I'll check out this article and I'll let you know, thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Hi @DavidMantilla, I've took out the Apache server and still getting the same response

Comment: If you have two different applications you should have two different context right ? But I don't see that in the js code. You should have something like this:
var url = "myserviceapp/myservice/get/" + somevar + "?callback=myCallback";

Comment: yes, I have two different contexts, the url shown is just an example. Actually, now I'm trying with Postman, just send the request to get the JSON response, and still the same problem, so is not the second app

Comment: So when you say that you receive login page code is the login page from services app ? Maybe another servlet ? Or a filter ? Could you post your web.xml code ?

Answer (score 0):

you are getting the login page code as response because the login is failed and you are redirected to the same page.. 
so before calling the service first you need to do the authentication and then by using the authentication token call the service..